# Loop through data multiple times with tf.train.shuffle_batch

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow to practice on mnist dataset which has 55,000 training images (5,000 images from the original 60,000 images from mnist was reserved for validation).

Currently I'm using tf.TFRecordReader to read in training tf.record, and subsequently using tf.train.shuffle_batch for training input. This process may be found in inputs function in mnist.py in https://bitbucket.org/jackywang529/tesorflow-sandbox/src.

However, I keep on getting the below error after step 2720.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_1_input/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 100, current size 0)
```

Thus I have 2 questions:

1. Why is it after step 2720? given that each step takes in a batch of 100, and I have 55,000 training images? If it were to go out of range, shouldn't it have done so at around step 550?
2. How can I keep looping over the dataset forever using tf.train.shuffle_batch? I'm not sure if it's a limitation set by the shuffle_batch implementation or something else.

Thank you!

Comment: Is something else reading from your queue? For instance, if you have summary statistics, they will consume elements from queue. If you are connecting your shuffle_batch to something like string_input_producer, the default behavior is to generate entries forever, you should check if you are setting `epochs` argument somewhere

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav! You were right and so was Filip in the response below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that your `tf.train.string_input_producer` has the argument `num_epochs=None` so that it cycles indefinitely?